# Error: WindowText is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener

Tags: java, awt, textfield

I have written a program to display a window with a label,textfield and a button.When the mouse is clicked on the textfield the program VirtualKeyboardTest.java should be called.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class WindowText implements MouseListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Frame f=new Frame("New Window");
        f.setSize(500,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Panel p = new Panel();
        Panel p1 = new Panel();
        Label lb = new Label("Click on textfield");
        TextField tf = new TextField(20);
        tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                new VirtualKeyboardTest();
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
        });

        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p.add(lb);
        p.add(tf);

        Button Submit=new Button("Submit");
        p.add(Submit);
        p1.add(p);
        f.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

But when i attempt to compile this program i am getting an error as

```
 WindowText.java:4: WindowText is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
    class WindowText implements MouseListener
    ^
    1 error
```

I can't understand why i get this error even though i have over ridden every method in MouseListener.

Comment: In this millennium, use Swing components rather than AWT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the methods that MouseListener has.

```
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
```

Must be overridden in MouseText.
But since you have an anonymous adapter it seems redundant for MouseText to implement MouseListener anyway.

Comment: @Gambler You already have `new MouseAdapter(){..}` (anonymous Adapter) in Main. And since you have no fields in MouseText, it appears to me that you don't need to implement MouseListener. Remove `implement MouseListener`and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
class WindowText implements MouseListener
```

It means that `WindowTest` should define a body for every* method declared in interface `MouseListener`

Error states clearly:  `mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)` has not been implemented in you class. So, you should implement that method to compile successfully.

(*) if the implementing class is abstract, it may not define a body and may mark the method as `abstract`. now it should be implemented by it's dervied class. I hope this clears the abstract word used in error statement.